# log4cpp and link error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, log4cpp

> log4cppLIB.lib(Appender.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for
>   '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in
>   H`tmlHelper.obj`

I have got this error message while trying to compile my program with log4cpp

After downloading the library, I unzipped, created an env variable then referenced to its 'include' folder in my project settings, so headers files are inclusive without error.
Next, I recompiled the project files in msvc10 and retrieved the lib and the dll files.

Then in my project I included
`#pragma comment (lib,"path to the lib file")`

in my main program (my application is a console one)

Compiling this program gives me the above link errors (I post only one as above but there are actually many - all such link errors)

I think I am wrong about my project settings and installation of the lob4cpp library (their document is out of date)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080668/iterator-debug-level-value-0-doesnt-match-value-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error ('_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' ) indicates that your mixing debug and release built objects, make sure to compile the log4cpp lib in Debug mode for Debug project and Release mode for Release project.